# How can I modify this code so that it is full height of whatever device screen it is viewed on?

Tags: html, css

How can I modify this code so that it is full height of whatever device screen it is viewed on?
I would like to make it so both rectangles maintain their relative proportions.

```css
.screen a {
  display: contents;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-center-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-center-horizontal>* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ray106 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 740px;
  width: 360px;
}

.ray106 .component-1-1 {
  background-color: #463af2;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 740px;
}

.ray106 .rectangle-2 {
  background-color: #f61a1a;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 677px;
  left: 33px;
  position: relative;
  top: 31px;
  width: 292px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; background: #ffffff">
  <input type="hidden" id="anPageName" name="page" value="ray106" />
  <div class="container-center-horizontal">
    <div class="ray106 screen">
      <div class="component-1-1">
        <div class="rectangle-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  Could you please some clarifying details of the desired behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ?  An image might be helpful here.  Also, please do not spam filler characters into your question to circumvent rules around minimum content length.  Welcome, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative to viewport units: `height: 100vh;` what means 100% of viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

Use "[relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units)" that refer to a proportion rather than a specific, finite unit.  Percentages, `em`s or viewport units would be some common examples.  Below I've swapped in viewport units:

```css
.screen a {
  display: contents;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-center-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-center-horizontal>* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ray106 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh; /* 740px */
  width: 48.6486486486vh; /* 360px / 740px */
}

.ray106 .component-1-1 {
  background-color: #463af2;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 100vh; /* 740px */
}

.ray106 .rectangle-2 {
  background-color: #f61a1a;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  height: 91.4864864865vh; /* 677 / 740 */
  left: 4.4594594595vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 4.1891891892vh;
  width: 39.4594594595vh; /*292 / 740 */
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; background: #ffffff">
  <input type="hidden" id="anPageName" name="page" value="ray106" />
  <div class="container-center-horizontal">
    <div class="ray106 screen">
      <div class="component-1-1">
        <div class="rectangle-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't mean modifying the size of the individual rectangle components, I mean making the entire container fit screen height.

Comment: @Overstack - As I stated in my comment on your original question, an image of your desired output would be helpful, as this, I believe, fits the original request-- the container will be full height in any viewport size and the rectangles will maintain their proportions.

Comment: The modifications you made produce the required output, thank you. But the method has me also modifying the shape of ray106 .rectangle-2. I would like to avoid this because if I have large number of rectangles per page it will mean tweaking the heights of all of them for every page. I was looking for a way to just scale up the whole page (or container) to fit any screen. Thanks

Comment: I see.  Then unfortunately I would suggest your question is lacking a sufficient [mcve] to understand your specific issue-- I would recommend updating with a complete [mcve] and full description of your needs.  Also, as a new user, you might consider reading [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide you with useful, meaningful guidance.  Good luck, and happy coding!